# Nginx.conf for angularjs application deployed on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: angularjs, nginx, static-files, cloud-foundry

I have an AngularJs application (v.1.5.7) which has definite routes like www.green.com/ , www.green.com/landing , www.green.com/home , etc,... I'm trying to deploy the angularjs application in PCF using Staticfile_buildpack. I have a custom Staticfile with contents as "root : application". I have my index.html, app.js and other angularjs controllers inside the "application" directory.

My angularJs config has the below routing config,

```
$routeProvider
.when("/landing", {
        templateUrl: "landing/landing.html",
        controller: 'LandingController'
    })
```

With the default nginx configuration, my base url (www.green.com/) & other internal routes (eg. /landing through ng-route & $location.path) were served properly. But when i refresh the landing page (www.green.com/landing) it gives me a 404 Not Found error. I understand that nginx is trying to find the directory named "landing" here.

In case of page refresh, I tried to redirect the request back to my base url through custom nginx.conf, so that my index.html will be loaded. 
My present nginx.conf looks like below,

```
http{
    server { 
        listen <%=ENV["PORT"] %>;

        index index.html;

        location /landing {
            rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
        }

        location /{
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
        }
    }   
}
```

When i tried to load my site, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server error & the below error lines in PCF logs.

```
[error] 54#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html",
```

However when i tried to load www.green.com/landing it is redirecting successfully to my base url and then giving me a 500 Internal Server error.

I tried the following nginx.conf

```
http{
    server { 
        listen <%=ENV["PORT"] %>;

        index /application/index.html;

        rewrite "^/landing" /application/index.html last;
    }   
}
```

But I got 404 Not Found error, with the below error in PCF logs,

```
[error] 49#0: *3 open() "/home/vcap/app/nginx/html/application/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

Please help me to create a working custom nginx.conf file in this case. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should rewrite your urls in config, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but it sounds like you want to enable push state routing.  https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#pushstate

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll definitely try push state routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled `html5Mode` in your code, you need to set base tag in index file.along with that,

```
server {
    server_name my-app;

    index index.html;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This is the Nginx Rewrites for angular site.

Comment: I have set base tag <base href="/"> in my index file. 

However as per your nginx.conf, I'm setting my root through staticfile as i mentioned in my question. But I'm not sure why the files are trying to be served from "/home/vcap/app/nginx/html/"

Comment: you might be uploading your assets folders to `/home/vcap/app/nginx/html/` right?

Comment: I have enabled html5mode. I solved the posted problem by disabling html5mode i.e by removing `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

With this change my url appears like www.green.com/#/landing and it is not throwing 404 for page refresh. I can survive with this for time being. But I like to learn about nginx configuration wrt Pivotal Cloud Foundry Staticfile_buildpack. Please continue sharing your thoughts. For now I'm marking Bheema's response as the answer.